# Pass a list of image objects to a R magick function instead of a vector

Tags: r, imagemagick, purrr

The `magick` package [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#layers) shows how to make a mosaic of a vector of image objects:

```
bigdata <- image_read('https://jeroen.github.io/images/bigdata.jpg')
frink <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")
logo <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png")
img <- c(bigdata, logo, frink)
image_mosaic(img)
```

This works great. However, as a result of using `purrr::map` with some function which takes an image file name and returns an image, I get a **list** of image objects, not a **vector**, and the `image_mosaic` will not accept this list.

Reproducible example (this is just a mock example, obviously I need this for more than 3 images!):

```
read_image_wrapper <- function(url) image_read(url)
urls <- c("https://jeroen.github.io/images/bigdata.jpg", "https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png", "https://jeroen.github.io/images/Rlogo.png")
images_list <- purrr::map(urls, read_image_wrapper)
image_mosaic(images_list)
```

> Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.

And `unlist`ing won't work.

So I either need to understand how to unlist `images_list` in a way which will make it an image object, or change my `purrr:map` approach (don't suppose there's a `purrr:map_img`, is there?)

Comment: `image_join(images_list)` : ref: https://rud.is/b/2017/09/18/mapping-fall-foliage-with-sf/ (also, do a `str(img)` in your first example to see what `magick` does to those first three images since you really don't have a "vector" of independent `magick` objects with it)

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks, this is what I was looking for, if you write it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: thanks both of you...I was just trying to solve this same question!

Comment: yes many thanks I too needed to solve this very issue !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we take a look at what `magick` does under the hood — https://github.com/ropensci/magick/blob/master/R/base.R#L58-L60 — we'll see that `c()` is really just a call to `image_join()` so you can just do `image_join(images_list)` to get what you need.